# How to get user profile in linkedin using access token

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I have used LinkedIn API to make registration call in my website, so when user get registered by linked in i am storing their all detail including LinkedIn Id, LinkedIn URL, and access token

Now I want to fetch their Linked latest detail again by cron but as you know i can't redirect to login page of linked in again.

But as i have access token and linked Id so how can I fetch the user detail on behalf of access token or user Id without let to the login page of linked in

I am stuck at this point from last two days, all you precious help is welcome

Answer (score -1):

Once you have an access token for a user, you can make any API calls on their behalf by following the process outlined here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#requests

Note that access tokens expire after 60 days, unless you refresh them.  Details on refreshing the tokens are here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#refresh